# Why is my program snapping out abruptly without any error?

Tags: c, pointers

My code is running weirdly due to some runtime error in pointer part.
This is my code which is acting weird because I made mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int*, int*);
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("Values of a and b after swapping are %d and %d respectively\n",a,b);
}
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *temp;
    printf("asdf");
    *temp=*a;
    printf("asdf");
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}
```

and the ouput is
**Enter the value of a : 5
Enter the value of b : 2
asdf**
I mistakenly made temp a pointer variable instead of simple integer variable. But why does my code doesn't work any further and ends up right there?

Answer (score 2):

In `swap`, `temp` is an uninitialized pointer, so you're corrupting memory.  But it shouldn't be a pointer at all.  Change it to:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

The reason the original code behaves oddly is because it's storing to the target of an uninitialized pointer.  That pointer could contain any value, so writing to its target could change any part of memory.  This is known as undefined behavior.  For example, it could modify a return address, or some other variable.  The behavior is specific to the particular compiler you're using, the options that are in effect, etc.  If you really want to know what's going on with a particular compiler, you'd need to look at the assembly code and the call sequence to see exactly what that uninitialized pointer contains and what effect modifying its target will have.

Comment: The OP's "I mistakenly made temp a pointer variable instead of simple integer variable" suggests that they realize their mistake already.  They seem to be asking about why that mistake provoked the particular consequences it did.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point.  I updated my answer with a note about the effects of writing to the target of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I may sound stupid but can someone poison this code by assigning null pointer some value at its location to terminate from wherever attacker wants to?

Comment: @PriyankDave To do something like that, the attacker would need to have some way to make unintended changes to the program memory in a somewhat predictable way.  A much more common case would be a program that inputs a string into a fixed-length array, and an attacker who send it a long string that results in data being written past the end of the array in some predictable way.  In a properly coded program, none of this should be possible.

Comment: Yeah, nowadays compiler already takes care of it. But I am just a wannabe cyber security engineer type person I am learning Programming and other coding stuffs in this 4 years of my University. So I keep thinking about possibilities like this.  :|

Comment: @TomKarzes you're right, there might have been a slight change in gcc I have in windows and I have in ubuntu. In windows it is snaping out of the program while in ubuntu values of a and b is being printed as it is, the value which is given and not being swapped. Sorry for my weak english.

Comment: @PriyankDave Keep in mind that your Windows vs. Ubuntu runtime environments, libraries, etc. are very different.  In particular, your process memory will be different in the two environments.  So writing to some undefined address could behave quite differently (and in fact, the undefined address itself could easily be different).  As I said, the only way to really know what's going on is to look at the assembly code, which could change from one build to another if your build environment isn't essentially frozen.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah got it, I will learn assembly language too to understand it deeply. I love to find depth of this.

Answer (score 1):

> why does my code doesn't work any further and ends up right there?

Your `swap` function makes the program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *temp; // an uninitialized pointer - no memory allocated

    *temp=*a;  // assigning to *temp - and temp may be pointing anywhere

    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}
```

The above assignment is what causes the problem. When a program has undefined behavior, anything can happen - like the sudden termination of the program.